# header doesn't redirect to another page ajax php

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql, ajax

I'm working on login form request using ajax concept. Below i've posted my codes related to login. It doesn't redirect to myaccount.php page. if i use this `echo'<script>window.location="myaccount.php";</script>';` javascript function  it will work properly. But, here i want to do with php. **it returns the myaccount.php results as a ajax message.**

[image: Error image]

I'm getting the error message using this `<div id="loginreturn"></div>`. Above I've posted an error image. myaccount.php page results also shows inside the `<div id="loginreturn"></div>`. That is my problem. it doesn't redirect to another php page. How to solve this error?

**login.php**

```
<?php
    ob_start();
    include('config.php');
    error_reporting(E_ALL | E_WARNING | E_NOTICE);
    ini_set('display_errors', TRUE);
    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST")
    {
        $user_email = $_POST['email'];
        $user_password = $_POST['password'];    
        $_SESSION['ses_uemail'] = $user_email;
        if(empty($user_email) || empty($user_password) )
        {
            echo "You must provide your email id and password";
            die();
        }       
        try
        {
            $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE EmailID = ? AND Password = ?");
            $conn->errorInfo();
            $stmt->bindParam('1', $user_email, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt->bindParam('2', $user_password, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt->execute();
            while($row = $stmt->fetch())
            {
                $rename = $row['Name'];
                $reemail = $row['EmailID'];
                $repassword = $row['Password'];
            }       
            if($reemail == $_SESSION['ses_uemail'] && $repassword == $user_password)
            {
                $_SESSION['ses_name'] = $rename;
                $_SESSION['ses_email'] = $reemail;
                $_SESSION['ses_password'] = $repassword;
                header('Location:myaccount.php');
            }   
            else
            {
                echo "Incorrect email id and password";
            }
        }
        catch(PDOException $e)
        {
            'Error : ' .$e->getMessage();
        }
    }
    ob_flush();     
?>
```

**ajax.js**

```
// ajax signin
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        jQuery("#registertologin").click(function() {

                jQuery("#loginreturn").html("<img src='img/loading.gif'/>");
                var postData = $(this).serializeArray();
                var formURL = $(this).attr("action");
                $.ajax( {
                    url : 'login.php',
                    type: "POST",
                    data :  $('#loginform').serialize(),
                    success:function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                        jQuery("#loginreturn").html('<pre><code class="returndata">'+data+'</code></pre>');
                        $("#loginform").submit_login(); //SUBMIT FORM
                    },
                    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) 
                    {
                        $("#loginreturn").html('<pre><code class="returndata">AJAX Request Failed<br/> textStatus='+textStatus+', errorThrown='+errorThrown+'</code></pre>');
                    }
                });
                e.preventDefault();  //STOP default action
            });
    });
```

**index.php**

```
<form name="loginform" id="loginform" >
        <table class="outlineborder" width="500" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
          <tr>
            <td height="35" colspan="2">
                <div class="signinform">SignIn Form</div>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td height="35" colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td width="150" height="35" class="rightalign">Email Id : </td>
            <td width="348"><input class="inputfield" type="text" name="email" /></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td height="35" class="rightalign">Password : </td>
            <td><input class="inputfield" type="password" name="password" /></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td height="35" colspan="2" align="right">
                <span class="forgetpassword">Forget Password ?</span>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td height="35" colspan="2" align="center">
                <div id="loginreturn"></div>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td height="35" colspan="2" align="center">
                <input class="btns" type="button" name="submit_login" id="registertologin" value="SignIn" />
                <input class="btns" type="button" value="Close" onclick="document.getElementById('login_signup').style.display='none'; document.getElementById('fade').style.display='none'" />
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
```

Comment: why you putting the header('Location:myaccount.php') in login page , you should put that in success function in ajax call

Answer (score 2):

Changes in 'login.php'

```
while($row = $stmt->fetch())
 {
      $rename = $row['Name'];
      $reemail = $row['EmailID'];
      $repassword = $row['Password'];
 }       
 if($reemail == $_SESSION['ses_uemail'] && $repassword == $user_password)
 {
      $_SESSION['ses_name'] = $rename;
      $_SESSION['ses_email'] = $reemail;
      $_SESSION['ses_password'] = $repassword;
      return true;
 }else
 {
      return false;
 }
```

Changes in 'ajax.js'

```
success:function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
if(data == true)
{
     window.location.href="myaccount.php"
}else
{
     jQuery("#loginreturn").html('<pre><code class="returndata">'+data+'</code></pre>');
     $("#loginform").submit_login(); //SUBMIT FORM
}

},
```

Maybe Its Help You...

Thanks

Comment: i tried this. but it doesn't redirect to next page. it returns an empty message. i'm getting the error like this `Uncaught ReferenceError: e is not defined`

Comment: Change your ajax function also check breakets of jquery

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

**login.php**

```
<?php
    ob_start();
    include('config.php');
    error_reporting(E_ALL | E_WARNING | E_NOTICE);
    ini_set('display_errors', TRUE);
    $msg        =   array();

    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST")
    {
        $user_email = $_POST['email'];
        $user_password = $_POST['password'];    
        $_SESSION['ses_uemail'] = $user_email;
        if(empty($user_email) || empty($user_password) )
        {
            echo "You must provide your email id and password";
            die();
        }       
        try
        {
            $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE EmailID = ? AND Password = ?");
            $conn->errorInfo();
            $stmt->bindParam('1', $user_email, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt->bindParam('2', $user_password, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt->execute();
            while($row = $stmt->fetch())
            {
                $rename = $row['Name'];
                $reemail = $row['EmailID'];
                $repassword = $row['Password'];
            }       
            if($reemail == $_SESSION['ses_uemail'] && $repassword == $user_password)
            {
                $_SESSION['ses_name'] = $rename;
                $_SESSION['ses_email'] = $reemail;
                $_SESSION['ses_password'] = $repassword;
                //header('Location:myaccount.php'); //no need
                return json_encode(array('error'=> false));

            }   
            else
            {
                //echo "Incorrect email id and password";
                return json_encode(array('error'=> true, 'msg'=> "Incorrect email id and password"));
            }
        }
        catch(PDOException $e)
        {
            //'Error : ' .$e->getMessage();
            return json_encode(array('error'=> true, 'msg'=> $e->getMessage()));
        }
    }
    ob_flush();     
?>
```

**ajax.js**

```
// ajax signin
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        jQuery("#registertologin").click(function() {

                jQuery("#loginreturn").html("<img src='img/loading.gif'/>");
                var postData = $(this).serializeArray();
                var formURL = $(this).attr("action");
                $.ajax( {
                    url : 'login.php',
                    type: "POST",
                    data :  $('#loginform').serialize(),
                    dataType:"json",
                    success:function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                         jQuery("#loginreturn").html('<pre><code class="returndata">'+data+'</code></pre>');
                        $("#loginform").submit_login(); //SUBMIT FORM 

                        if(data.error)
                        {
                            console.log('data.msg'); 
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            window.location.href = 'myaccount.php';
                        }
                    },
                    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) 
                    {
                        $("#loginreturn").html('<pre><code class="returndata">AJAX Request Failed<br/> textStatus='+textStatus+', errorThrown='+errorThrown+'</code></pre>');
                    }
                });
                e.preventDefault();  //STOP default action
            });
    });
```

Comment: @Beginner try to check console , what did it say ?

Comment: i'm getting this error `Uncaught ReferenceError: json is not defined`

Comment: @Beginner try now , hope it will work now , edited both login.php and ajax.js please take the updated one

Comment: now i got this error `Uncaught ReferenceError: e is not defined`. it returns an ajax error AJAX Request Failed  textStatus=parsererror, errorThrown=SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input...

Comment: @Beginner comment out  e.preventDefault(); , and check

Comment: still i got same error mate... Uncaught ReferenceError: e is not defined